# How are AWS IAM server certificates meant to be used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

The `aws iam upload-server-certificate` command in the AWS CLI allows one to upload a certificate. However, I don't know how it can be applied afterwards. The `aws iam` commands include listing, modifying and deleting certificates, but not connecting them with any resources. Can they be used from EC2? Also, they don't seem to appear on the AWS Certificate Manager.

Comment: I think IAM certificates are effectively deprecated. Suggest you look into AWS Certificate Manager https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/ . ACM created or imported certificates can be used for ALBs and in a few other services.

Comment: @Tim there are regions in which ACM is not available (those in China mostly) where uploading your certs to IAM could become handy

Comment: China is a bit of an edge case with AWS, but you could be right, I've never used China regions.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use ACM for storing (or issuing certificates), but as per my comment above in case ACM is not supported within a region then you can upload the certificate to IAM.

Such a certificate could then be used in an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-certificates.html#add-certificates) or [Network Load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-tls-listener.html) or by setting up a [Custom SSL in your CloudFront distribution.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-ssl-certificate-cloudfront/)